# How to Handle JSON Response with Rx2Java and Retrofit

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

Before i make use of Rxjava 1.version.When it comes to RxJava2 which one should i use ,
I created my API service with Observable  like

```
Single<T>  doSomething();
```

in Rx2 ,i replace Single with `Observable`

how should i handle Response  in Controller,

Answer (score 0):

If your API returns a response that you care about, use `Single`. If you aren't interested in the response body of your API call and care only about response/success states, use `Completable`.

Comment: It would be great if you can share me the snippet,i need first criteria.